# Estilizando html5 datepicker

Tags: css, html5

Sei que é possível estilizar o `input date` do `html5`.

```css
::-webkit-datetime-edit { padding: 1em; }
::-webkit-datetime-edit-fields-wrapper { background: silver; }
::-webkit-datetime-edit-text { color: red; padding: 0 0.3em; }
::-webkit-datetime-edit-month-field { color: blue; }
::-webkit-datetime-edit-day-field { color: green; }
::-webkit-datetime-edit-year-field { color: purple; }
::-webkit-inner-spin-button { display: none; }
::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator { background: orange; }
```

```html
<input type="date" min='2019-10-12'>
```

Porém, como eu estilizo os dias que estão bloqueados pelo atributo `min` ?

Gostaria de deixar em vermelho os dias bloqueados.

Comment: Acredito que não seja possível estilizar o calendário pois todo navegador implementa seu próprio calendário de maneira diferente. É melhor utilizar plugins alternativos para isso como o datepicker do [jquery](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) ou do [bootstrap](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: Não tem como porque o calendário é gerado pelo navegador, e na verdade ele não existe no DOM, apenas o input.

Answer (score 1):

Qualquer forma de estilização deste ***datepicker*** gerado pelo navegador não passaria de uma mera ***gambiarra***.

A forma mais estável e que garante a compatibilidade entre todos os navegadores é usar um ***input comum*** e criar um ***datepicker*** nele.

Essa forma é mais trabalhosa, mas calma! Têm pessoas que já resolveram seu problema, segue o link dos plugins de datepicker que eu costumo usar.

Bootstrap:
https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Materialize CSS:
https://materializecss.com/pickers.html

*Espero ter ajudado, boa sorte!*